# Group image uploads by same user in a mixed type array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, nested

I have an array with different allocated types such as **imageLike**, **imageUpload** etc

I have been trying to reduce the array so it would group all **imageUpload** types by the same user and then nest them in one **images: []** array while not altering all other data types.

How can I reduce the array to only nest **imageUpload** types into their designated user object **images: []**?

Here is what I have come up with:

```
$('.button').click(function(e) {
        let button = $(this);    
        const mappedNotifications = [
        {
            "id":17,
            "type":"comment",
            "sender":17,
            "recipient":3,
            "itemId":5,
            "commentImageId":19,
            "replyImageId":"",
            "imageLikeImageId":"",
            "body":"great shot",
            "created":"2019-10-09T20:18:47.000Z",
            "username":"golfer1",
            "userThumbnail":"images/thumb.jpeg",
            "imageLikeThumbnail":"images/default.jpg",
            "imageUploadThumbnail":"images/default.jpg",
            "imageCommentThumbnail":"images/thumb.jpeg",
            "imageComment":"great shot",
            "imageReplyThumbnail":"images/default.jpg",
            "imageReply":""
        },
        {
            "id":16,
            "type":"imageLike",
            "sender":17,
            "recipient":3,
            "itemId":19,
            "commentImageId":"",
            "replyImageId":"",
            "imageLikeImageId":19,
            "body":"",
            "created":"2019-10-09T20:18:40.000Z",
            "username":"golfer1",
            "userThumbnail":"images/thumb.jpeg",
            "imageLikeThumbnail":"images/thumb.jpeg",
            "imageUploadThumbnail":"images/default.jpg",
            "imageCommentThumbnail":"images/default.jpg",
            "imageComment":"",
            "imageReplyThumbnail":"images/default.jpg",
            "imageReply":""
        },
        {
            "id":15,
            "type":"imageLike",
            "sender":17,
            "recipient":3,
            "itemId":21,
            "commentImageId":"",
            "replyImageId":"",
            "imageLikeImageId":21,
            "body":"",
            "created":"2019-10-09T20:18:32.000Z",
            "username":"golfer1",
            "userThumbnail":"images/thumb.jpeg",
            "imageLikeThumbnail":"images/thumb.jpeg",
            "imageUploadThumbnail":"images/default.jpg",
            "imageCommentThumbnail":"images/default.jpg",
            "imageComment":"",
            "imageReplyThumbnail":"images/default.jpg",
            "imageReply":""
        },
        {
            "id":14,
            "type":"imageUpload",
            "sender":17,
            "recipient":null,
            "itemId":35,
            "commentImageId":"",
            "replyImageId":"",
            "imageLikeImageId":"",
            "body":"",
            "created":"2019-10-09T19:23:48.000Z",
            "username":"golfer1",
            "userThumbnail":"images/thumb.jpeg",
            "imageLikeThumbnail":"images/default.jpg",
            "imageUploadThumbnail":"images/thumb.jpeg",
            "imageCommentThumbnail":"images/default.jpg",
            "imageComment":"",
            "imageReplyThumbnail":"images/default.jpg",
            "imageReply":""
        },
        {
            "id":13,
            "type":"imageUpload",
            "sender":17,
            "recipient":null,
            "itemId":34,
            "commentImageId":"",
            "replyImageId":"",
            "imageLikeImageId":"",
            "body":"",
            "created":"2019-10-09T19:23:42.000Z",
            "username":"golfer1",
            "userThumbnail":"images/thumb.jpeg",
            "imageLikeThumbnail":"images/default.jpg",
            "imageUploadThumbnail":"images/thumb.jpeg",
            "imageCommentThumbnail":"images/default.jpg",
            "imageComment":"",
            "imageReplyThumbnail":"images/default.jpg",
            "imageReply":""
        },
        {
            "id":12,
            "type":"imageUpload",
            "sender":17,
            "recipient":null,
            "itemId":33,
            "commentImageId":"",
            "replyImageId":"",
            "imageLikeImageId":"",
            "body":"",
            "created":"2019-10-09T19:23:36.000Z",
            "username":"golfer1",
            "userThumbnail":"images/thumb.jpeg",
            "imageLikeThumbnail":"images/default.jpg",
            "imageUploadThumbnail":"images/thumb.jpeg",
            "imageCommentThumbnail":"images/default.jpg",
            "imageComment":"",
            "imageReplyThumbnail":"images/default.jpg",
            "imageReply":""
        },
        {
            "id":11,
            "type":"imageUpload",
            "sender":17,
            "recipient":null,
            "itemId":30,
            "commentImageId":"",
            "replyImageId":"",
            "imageLikeImageId":"",
            "body":"",
            "created":"2019-10-09T19:04:08.000Z",
            "username":"golfer1",
            "userThumbnail":"images/thumb.jpeg",
            "imageLikeThumbnail":"images/default.jpg",
            "imageUploadThumbnail":"images/thumb.jpeg",
            "imageCommentThumbnail":"images/default.jpg",
            "imageComment":"",
            "imageReplyThumbnail":"images/default.jpg",
            "imageReply":""
        }
    ];

    const object = {};
    const nestedNotifications = mappedNotifications.reduce(function(result, data) {
        if (!object[data.id]) {
            if(data.type === 'imageUpload'){
                // UPLOAD TYPE
                if(!object[data.sender] ){}
                else{
                    object[data.id] = {
                        id: data.id,
                        sender: data.sender,
                        type: data.type,
                        username: data.username,
                        userThumbnail: data.userThumbnail,
                        images: []
                    }
                    result.push(object[data.id]);
                }
            }
            else{
                // OTHER TYPES
                object[data.id] = {
                    id: data.id,
                    sender: data.sender,
                    type: data.type,
                    username: data.username,
                    userThumbnail: data.userThumbnail,
                }
                result.push(object[data.id]);
            }
        }

        if(data.type === 'imageUpload'){
           //console.log('object[data.sender]: ', object[data.sender])
           object[data.id].images.push({
                id: data.id,
                itemId: data.itemId,
                imageUploadThumbnail: data.imageUploadThumbnail,

            });
        }
        return result;
    }, [])

    console.log('nestedNotifications Output: ', nestedNotifications)
});
```

#### current output:

```
[
    {
        id: 17
        sender: 17
        type: "comment"
        userThumbnail: "images/thumb.jpeg"
        username: "golfer1",
    },
    {
        id: 16
        sender: 17
        type: "imageLike"
        userThumbnail: "images/thumb.jpeg"
        username: "golfer1"
    },
    {
        id: 15
        sender: 17
        type: "imageLike"
        userThumbnail: "images/thumb.jpeg"
        username: "golfer1"
    },
    {
        id: 14
        sender: 17
        type: "imageUpload"
        userThumbnail: "images/thumb.jpeg"
        username: "golfer1",
        images[
            id: 14,
            imageUploadThumbnail: "images/thumb.jpeg",
            itemId: 35
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 13
        sender: 17
        type: "imageUpload"
        userThumbnail: "images/thumb.jpeg"
        username: "golfer1",
        images[
            id: 13,
            imageUploadThumbnail: "images/thumb.jpeg",
            itemId: 34
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 12
        images: Array [ {…} ]
        sender: 17
        type: "imageUpload"
        userThumbnail: "images/thumb.jpeg"
        username: "golfer1",
        images[
            id: 12,
            imageUploadThumbnail: "images/thumb.jpeg",
            itemId: 33
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 11
        sender: 17
        type: "imageUpload"
        userThumbnail: "images/thumb.jpeg"
        username: "golfer1",
        images[
            id: 11,
            imageUploadThumbnail: "images/thumb.jpeg",
            itemId: 30
        ]
    }
]
```

#### Desired outcome:

```
[
    {
        id: 17
        sender: 17
        type: "comment"
        userThumbnail: "images/thumb.jpeg"
        username: "golfer1",
    },
    {
        id: 16
        sender: 17
        type: "imageLike"
        userThumbnail: "images/thumb.jpeg"
        username: "golfer1"
    },
    {
        id: 15
        sender: 17
        type: "imageLike"
        userThumbnail: "images/thumb.jpeg"
        username: "golfer1"
    },
    {
        id: 14
        sender: 17
        type: "imageUpload"
        userThumbnail: "images/thumb.jpeg"
        username: "golfer1",
        images[
            {
                id: 14,
                imageUploadThumbnail: "images/thumb.jpeg",
                itemId: 35
            },
            {
                id: 13,
                imageUploadThumbnail: "images/thumb.jpeg",
                itemId: 34
            },
            {
                id: 12,
                imageUploadThumbnail: "images/thumb.jpeg",
                itemId: 33
            },
            {
                id: 11,
                imageUploadThumbnail: "images/thumb.jpeg",
                itemId: 30
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

#### Example mockup of desired outcome:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/goW8r.jpg

Comment: is lodash and option?

Comment: @MohammedShammout yeah as I’m using Nodejs

Comment: I took another look at your question and I'm really not sure what you want, the Desired outcome doesn't match what you say at the beginning.

Comment: @MohammedShammout if one user has more than one imageUpload type then I want it to be nested under an images array in one object wrather than having say 4 different objects by the same user. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at how I've done it here. I have commented on the code with details of what is being done.

The only difference in output is that I'm storing the `uploadImage`s in the original sender object instead of inside the first such occurrence of that object. I think this is a better approach from a data organisation standpoint.

```js
const sort = (items) => {

  // Let's declare some useful functions:
  // isUpload tests if an item is an imageUpload while cherrypickItem returns the same object with a reduced set of key/values
  const isUpload = item => item.type == "imageUpload"
  const cherrypickItem = (item, keys) => keys.reduce((cherrypicked, propertyName) => ({...cherrypicked, [propertyName]: item[propertyName]}), {})

  // allTypes will be an array of all items apart from imageUploads, while imageUploads will be the inverse of that
  const allTypes = items.filter(item => !isUpload(item))
  const imageUploads = items.filter(isUpload)

  // Here we are creating a hash of the imageUploads sorted into keys by the sender id
  const imageUploadsBySenderId = imageUploads.reduce((items, item) => {

    return {
      ...items,
      [item.sender]: items[item.sender] ? [...items[item.sender], item] : [item]
    }
  }, {})
  
  return allTypes.map(item => {

    // use our cherrypickItem function to return a reduced item object
    let newItem = cherrypickItem(item, ['id', 'sender', 'type', 'userThumbnail', 'username'])

    // if a lookup of our imageUploads shows that there are existing items from the sender
    if (imageUploadsBySenderId[item.id]) {

      // merge these into the item under the key 'images'
      newItem = {
        ...newItem,
        images: imageUploadsBySenderId[item.sender].map(imageUpload => {

          return cherrypickItem(imageUpload, ['id', 'imageUploadThumbnail', 'itemId'])

        })
      }
    }

    // return the new item to the map
    return newItem

  })
}

const sorted = sort([
  {
    "id":17,
    "type":"comment",
    "sender":17,
    "recipient":3,
    "itemId":5,
    "commentImageId":19,
    "replyImageId":"",
    "imageLikeImageId":"",
    "body":"great shot",
    "created":"2019-10-09T20:18:47.000Z",
    "username":"golfer1",
    "userThumbnail":"images/thumb.jpeg",
    "imageLikeThumbnail":"images/default.jpg",
    "imageUploadThumbnail":"images/default.jpg",
    "imageCommentThumbnail":"images/thumb.jpeg",
    "imageComment":"great shot",
    "imageReplyThumbnail":"images/default.jpg",
    "imageReply":""
  },
  {
    "id":16,
    "type":"imageLike",
    "sender":17,
    "recipient":3,
    "itemId":19,
    "commentImageId":"",
    "replyImageId":"",
    "imageLikeImageId":19,
    "body":"",
    "created":"2019-10-09T20:18:40.000Z",
    "username":"golfer1",
    "userThumbnail":"images/thumb.jpeg",
    "imageLikeThumbnail":"images/thumb.jpeg",
    "imageUploadThumbnail":"images/default.jpg",
    "imageCommentThumbnail":"images/default.jpg",
    "imageComment":"",
    "imageReplyThumbnail":"images/default.jpg",
    "imageReply":""
  },
  {
    "id":15,
    "type":"imageLike",
    "sender":17,
    "recipient":3,
    "itemId":21,
    "commentImageId":"",
    "replyImageId":"",
    "imageLikeImageId":21,
    "body":"",
    "created":"2019-10-09T20:18:32.000Z",
    "username":"golfer1",
    "userThumbnail":"images/thumb.jpeg",
    "imageLikeThumbnail":"images/thumb.jpeg",
    "imageUploadThumbnail":"images/default.jpg",
    "imageCommentThumbnail":"images/default.jpg",
    "imageComment":"",
    "imageReplyThumbnail":"images/default.jpg",
    "imageReply":""
  },
  {
    "id":14,
    "type":"imageUpload",
    "sender":17,
    "recipient":null,
    "itemId":35,
    "commentImageId":"",
    "replyImageId":"",
    "imageLikeImageId":"",
    "body":"",
    "created":"2019-10-09T19:23:48.000Z",
    "username":"golfer1",
    "userThumbnail":"images/thumb.jpeg",
    "imageLikeThumbnail":"images/default.jpg",
    "imageUploadThumbnail":"images/thumb.jpeg",
    "imageCommentThumbnail":"images/default.jpg",
    "imageComment":"",
    "imageReplyThumbnail":"images/default.jpg",
    "imageReply":""
  },
  {
    "id":13,
    "type":"imageUpload",
    "sender":17,
    "recipient":null,
    "itemId":34,
    "commentImageId":"",
    "replyImageId":"",
    "imageLikeImageId":"",
    "body":"",
    "created":"2019-10-09T19:23:42.000Z",
    "username":"golfer1",
    "userThumbnail":"images/thumb.jpeg",
    "imageLikeThumbnail":"images/default.jpg",
    "imageUploadThumbnail":"images/thumb.jpeg",
    "imageCommentThumbnail":"images/default.jpg",
    "imageComment":"",
    "imageReplyThumbnail":"images/default.jpg",
    "imageReply":""
  },
  {
    "id":12,
    "type":"imageUpload",
    "sender":17,
    "recipient":null,
    "itemId":33,
    "commentImageId":"",
    "replyImageId":"",
    "imageLikeImageId":"",
    "body":"",
    "created":"2019-10-09T19:23:36.000Z",
    "username":"golfer1",
    "userThumbnail":"images/thumb.jpeg",
    "imageLikeThumbnail":"images/default.jpg",
    "imageUploadThumbnail":"images/thumb.jpeg",
    "imageCommentThumbnail":"images/default.jpg",
    "imageComment":"",
    "imageReplyThumbnail":"images/default.jpg",
    "imageReply":""
  },
  {
    "id":11,
    "type":"imageUpload",
    "sender":17,
    "recipient":null,
    "itemId":30,
    "commentImageId":"",
    "replyImageId":"",
    "imageLikeImageId":"",
    "body":"",
    "created":"2019-10-09T19:04:08.000Z",
    "username":"golfer1",
    "userThumbnail":"images/thumb.jpeg",
    "imageLikeThumbnail":"images/default.jpg",
    "imageUploadThumbnail":"images/thumb.jpeg",
    "imageCommentThumbnail":"images/default.jpg",
    "imageComment":"",
    "imageReplyThumbnail":"images/default.jpg",
    "imageReply":""
  }
])

console.log(sorted)
```

## **Update**

If you really want to go with the desired output in your question, then the below should suffice. I would reconsider re-using an id and thereby duplicating data in this manner, however.

```js
const sort = (items) => {

  // Let's declare some useful functions:
  // isUpload tests if an item is an imageUpload while cherrypickItem returns the same object with a reduced set of key/values
  const isUpload = item => item.type == "imageUpload"
  const cherrypickItem = (item, keys) => keys.reduce((cherrypicked, propertyName) => ({...cherrypicked, [propertyName]: item[propertyName]}), {})

  // allTypes will be an array of all items apart from imageUploads, while imageUploads will be the inverse of that
  const allTypes = items.filter(item => !isUpload(item))
  const imageUploads = items.filter(isUpload)

  // Here we are creating a hash of the imageUploads sorted into keys by the sender id
  const imageUploadsBySenderId = imageUploads.reduce((items, item) => {

    return {
      ...items,
      [item.sender]: items[item.sender] ? [...items[item.sender], item] : [item]
    }
  }, {})

  const imageUploadItems = Object.keys(imageUploadsBySenderId).map(senderId => {
    
    return {
      // hoist the first item in the array
      ...cherrypickItem(imageUploadsBySenderId[senderId][0], ['id', 'sender', 'type', 'userThumbnail', 'username']),
      // and then nest all the items in an images property
      images: imageUploadsBySenderId[senderId].map(item => cherrypickItem(item, ['id', 'imageUploadThumbnail', 'itemId']))
    }
  })

  return allTypes.map(item => {

    return cherrypickItem(item, ['id', 'sender', 'type', 'userThumbnail', 'username'])

  }).concat(imageUploadItems)
}

const sorted = sort([
  {
    "id":17,
    "type":"comment",
    "sender":17,
    "recipient":3,
    "itemId":5,
    "commentImageId":19,
    "replyImageId":"",
    "imageLikeImageId":"",
    "body":"great shot",
    "created":"2019-10-09T20:18:47.000Z",
    "username":"golfer1",
    "userThumbnail":"images/thumb.jpeg",
    "imageLikeThumbnail":"images/default.jpg",
    "imageUploadThumbnail":"images/default.jpg",
    "imageCommentThumbnail":"images/thumb.jpeg",
    "imageComment":"great shot",
    "imageReplyThumbnail":"images/default.jpg",
    "imageReply":""
  },
  {
    "id":16,
    "type":"imageLike",
    "sender":17,
    "recipient":3,
    "itemId":19,
    "commentImageId":"",
    "replyImageId":"",
    "imageLikeImageId":19,
    "body":"",
    "created":"2019-10-09T20:18:40.000Z",
    "username":"golfer1",
    "userThumbnail":"images/thumb.jpeg",
    "imageLikeThumbnail":"images/thumb.jpeg",
    "imageUploadThumbnail":"images/default.jpg",
    "imageCommentThumbnail":"images/default.jpg",
    "imageComment":"",
    "imageReplyThumbnail":"images/default.jpg",
    "imageReply":""
  },
  {
    "id":15,
    "type":"imageLike",
    "sender":17,
    "recipient":3,
    "itemId":21,
    "commentImageId":"",
    "replyImageId":"",
    "imageLikeImageId":21,
    "body":"",
    "created":"2019-10-09T20:18:32.000Z",
    "username":"golfer1",
    "userThumbnail":"images/thumb.jpeg",
    "imageLikeThumbnail":"images/thumb.jpeg",
    "imageUploadThumbnail":"images/default.jpg",
    "imageCommentThumbnail":"images/default.jpg",
    "imageComment":"",
    "imageReplyThumbnail":"images/default.jpg",
    "imageReply":""
  },
  {
    "id":14,
    "type":"imageUpload",
    "sender":17,
    "recipient":null,
    "itemId":35,
    "commentImageId":"",
    "replyImageId":"",
    "imageLikeImageId":"",
    "body":"",
    "created":"2019-10-09T19:23:48.000Z",
    "username":"golfer1",
    "userThumbnail":"images/thumb.jpeg",
    "imageLikeThumbnail":"images/default.jpg",
    "imageUploadThumbnail":"images/thumb.jpeg",
    "imageCommentThumbnail":"images/default.jpg",
    "imageComment":"",
    "imageReplyThumbnail":"images/default.jpg",
    "imageReply":""
  },
  {
    "id":13,
    "type":"imageUpload",
    "sender":17,
    "recipient":null,
    "itemId":34,
    "commentImageId":"",
    "replyImageId":"",
    "imageLikeImageId":"",
    "body":"",
    "created":"2019-10-09T19:23:42.000Z",
    "username":"golfer1",
    "userThumbnail":"images/thumb.jpeg",
    "imageLikeThumbnail":"images/default.jpg",
    "imageUploadThumbnail":"images/thumb.jpeg",
    "imageCommentThumbnail":"images/default.jpg",
    "imageComment":"",
    "imageReplyThumbnail":"images/default.jpg",
    "imageReply":""
  },
  {
    "id":12,
    "type":"imageUpload",
    "sender":17,
    "recipient":null,
    "itemId":33,
    "commentImageId":"",
    "replyImageId":"",
    "imageLikeImageId":"",
    "body":"",
    "created":"2019-10-09T19:23:36.000Z",
    "username":"golfer1",
    "userThumbnail":"images/thumb.jpeg",
    "imageLikeThumbnail":"images/default.jpg",
    "imageUploadThumbnail":"images/thumb.jpeg",
    "imageCommentThumbnail":"images/default.jpg",
    "imageComment":"",
    "imageReplyThumbnail":"images/default.jpg",
    "imageReply":""
  },
  {
    "id":11,
    "type":"imageUpload",
    "sender":17,
    "recipient":null,
    "itemId":30,
    "commentImageId":"",
    "replyImageId":"",
    "imageLikeImageId":"",
    "body":"",
    "created":"2019-10-09T19:04:08.000Z",
    "username":"golfer1",
    "userThumbnail":"images/thumb.jpeg",
    "imageLikeThumbnail":"images/default.jpg",
    "imageUploadThumbnail":"images/thumb.jpeg",
    "imageCommentThumbnail":"images/default.jpg",
    "imageComment":"",
    "imageReplyThumbnail":"images/default.jpg",
    "imageReply":""
  }
])

console.log(sorted)
```

Comment: this is almost (90%) what I've been trying to achieve, thank you, your code created an array of almost all types **[imageLike, comment, (but not imageUpload)]** and then nested an array of imageUploads in the "type: comment" rather than "imageUpload" which destroyes the original "comment" object.

Comment: I thought the comment object's id of 17 was the id referenced in the uploadImage's `sender` value? I.e the imageUpload's are children of the comment. What is strange about your desired output is the fact that you nest the imageUpload's inside the first imageUpload. So you have two id's containing 14. This defeats the purpose of an 'id' which, conventionally, should represent a unique "thing".

Comment: There are comments, image likes and image uploads, they are not the same objects nor are they children of said objects. They’re all separate unless there is more than one object that is an image upload and it’s by the same user, then it should be nested as an image array inside one object. A way of showing the latest photos uploaded by a user amongst other forms of activity by that user (image likes etc). The first object should keep its ID intact and then if more objects contain the same user id and are the of the imageUpload type then an array should be created to form a nested array

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try this but I think this should work if I understood your requirement correctly.

```js
const yourData = [//your data here];
let data = {};
yourData.forEach(attach => {
  if(Object.keys(data).includes(attach.username)) {
    data[attach.username] = { ...data[attach.username], 
        images: [...data[attach.username].images,
         { id: attach.id,
           imageUploadThumbnail: attach.imageUploadThumbnail,
           itemId: attach.itemId 
           //other fields you want
        }]};
  } else {
    data[attach.username] = { id: attach.id,
        sender: attach.sender,
        type: attach.type,
        userThumbnail: attach.userThumbnail,
        // other fields you want
        username: attach.username, images: [{ 
            id: attach.id,
            imageUploadThumbnail: attach.imageUploadThumbnail,
            itemId: attach.itemId 
            //ohter fields you want
    }]};
  }
});
const desired = Object.keys(data).map(key => data[key]);
```

Comment: thanks for trying but the answer @shennan provided was closer to what I was looking for. Really appreciate the effort

Comment: anytime bro, yeah I can tell from your updated question that I got it all wrong.